# Showing displayField value instead of empty Text in combo Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm trying to show display field value in the combo instead of empty text value. How can I achieve this? Data is populated in combo through local server. I have tried to implement a listener, but there's no change in output.

```
listener: {

  beforeRender:function(boxs1) {
    //if(!this.allowBlank) {
      var r1 = findRecordByDisplay(CIVIL) ;
      Ext.getCmp('boxs1').setValue(fullName);
    //}
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not to set the initial value through 'value' property?

Comment: @triclozan yes we can but i m trying to do it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.QuickTips.init();
Ext.namespace('Ext.exampledata');
Ext.exampledata.zone = [
['us', 'US', 'US Zone'],
['japan', 'JAPAN', 'Japan Zone'],
['eu', 'EUROPE', 'Europe Zone']
];
var test=  new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id:'appwarpZoneId',
    fieldLabel: 'Zone',
    hiddenName:'zone',
    renderTo:'sid',
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: ['abbr', 'zone'],
        data : Ext.exampledata.zone
    }),
    valueField:'abbr',
    value:'us',
    emptyText : 'Please Select ...',
    displayField:'zone',
    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'local',
    editable:false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    selectOnFocus:true,
    anchor: '25%'
})
});
```

Comment: sir i m not populating data through local store  and i want to implement this thing only through listener.

Answer (score 0):

Use render or afterrender event to set the value.

```
listener:{
    afterrender:function(boxs1){
        //if(!this.allowBlank){
        var r1 = findRecordByDisplay(CIVIL) ;
        Ext.getCmp('boxs1').setValue(fullName);
    //}
    }
}
```

Comment: What is findRecordByDisplay and fullName.

Comment: findRecordByDisplay-Finds the record by searching values in the displayField & fullName is the field

Answer (score 0):

you have to know

setRawValue() => displayField

setValue() => valueField